# Is there any way to dynamically access a superglobal?

Tags: php, superglobals

As a web developer, I'm always using this approach to something like a login form or other “save” operation (ignoring the dangers of directly accessing input variables):

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login')
{
    // we're probably logging in, so let's process that here
}
```

To make this less tedious and keeping in line with DRY principles (sort of), I cooked this up:

```
function isset_and_is ($superglobal, $key, $value)
{
    $ref = '_' . strtoupper($superglobal);

    return isset($$ref[$key]) && $$ref[$key] == $value;
}

if (isset_and_is('post', 'action', 'login'))
{
    // we're probably logging in, so let's process that here
}
```

This fails miserably, despite my oh-so-clever use of dynamic variable names to access the superglobal.

So, I'm stuck using this ugly:

```
function isset_and_is ($superglobal, $key, $value)
{
    switch (strtoupper($superglobal))
    {
        case 'GET':     $ref =& $_GET;     break;
        case 'POST':    $ref =& $_POST;    break;
        case 'REQUEST': $ref =& $_REQUEST; break;
        default:        die('megafail');   return;
    }

    return isset($ref[$key]) && $ref[$key] == $value;
}

if (isset_and_is('post', 'action', 'login'))
{
    // we're probably logging in, so let's process that here
}
```

**My question:** Is there a way to dynamically access the superglobal variables like I'm attempting to do in my second code sample? If no, is there a better/more efficient way to accomplish what I'm doing in the third code sample?

---

**My solution:** Thanks to [Tom Haigh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558515/is-there-any-way-to-dynamically-access-a-superglobal/3558546#3558546), here's the final code I'll be going with:

```
function isset_and_is ($superglobal, $key, $value)
{
    $ref =& $GLOBALS['_' . strtoupper($superglobal)];

    return isset($ref[$key]) && $ref[$key] == $value;
}
```

Comment: And what is wrong with the first sample?

Comment: IMO the first sample is clearer, DRYer and easy for anyone who knows PHP to understand. Whereas the other ones...

Comment: NullUserException: Valid point, but I'm the only person ever using this code, unless you'd like to use it too.

Comment: Well, if you want to introduce unnecessary complexity and overhead to your code, who am I to deny you? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function test($var) {
    //this 
    var_dump( $GLOBALS[$var] );

    //or this
    global $$var; //this is needed even for superglobals
    var_dump($$var);
}

test('_GET');
```

so you could use something like this in your case

```
function isset_and_is ($superglobal, $key, $value) {
    $var = '_' . $superglobal;
    return isset($GLOBALS[$var]) && ($GLOBALS[$var][$key] == $value);
}

$is_login = isset_and_is('GET', 'action', 'login');
```

Or alternatively you can take the variable by reference and use `isset()`, e.g.

```
function get_var(& $var) {
    if (isset($var)) {
        return $var;
    }
    return null;
}

//will not give you a notice if not set
$post_var = get_var($_POST['var']);

if (get_var($_GET['action']) == 'login') {
    //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to fetch from only one source, go with Tom's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22224/tom-haigh).

However, if you're doing this for every variable, i.e., if you always admit that data can come from two sources, the best alternative is to merge them.

You could use `$_REQUEST`, but I'd advise you against it. The order it considers POST and GET data is `php.ini` configurable, and it includes other sources.

Do something like:

```
$data = array_merge($_GET, $_POST); //POST has precedence
```

and then get your data from `$data`.

Comment: Doesn't GET have precedence here? I mean, if `$_POST['var']` and `$_GET['var']` are set, it will pick `$_GET['var']`

Comment: I'm not admitting data can always come from two sources; on the contrary, data will only ever come from one of the superglobals, depending on where I'm accessing it. But, I want to be able to re-use this function.

Answer (score 1):

How about: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

```
function isset_and_is ($superglobal, $key, $value) {
  switch($superglobal) {
    case 'post':
      $type = INPUT_POST;
      break;
    case 'get':
      $type = INPUT_GET;
      break;
  }
  $var = filter_input($type,$key);
  if(is_null($var)) return false;
  return($var == $value);
}
```

Comment: Your answer completely ignores the question, and simply provides an equally crufty solution to my third code sample.

Comment: Honestly, I can't see how it's ignoring your question. Given you can actually use INPUT_* constants as an argument to this function to get rid of the switch, it cen become a really nice solution IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

When `$_REQUEST` by default contains the contents of `$_GET` and `$_POST`, why do you need switch-case. You can directly use this and eliminate `$superglobal`:

```
function isset_and_is ($key, $value)
{
    return isset($_REQUEST[$key]) && ($_REQUEST[$key] == $value);
}
```

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is unsafe if I only want to allow logins via `POST`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP, operator `@` suppresses warnings while evaluating an expression. For example, `$array[$key]` returns the value with that key if it exists or `null` if not, but it raises a warning if the key does not exist. Adding the `@` operator to produce `@$array[$key]` makes it equivalent to `array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : null`. In fact, `isset($something)` is only another way of saying `@$something === null`.

So try this:

```
if (@$_POST['action'] === 'login')
{
    // we're probably logging in, so let's process that here
}
```

My PHP projects use something similar to the snippet in the [documentation of `ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php). This adds fail-fast semantics, where PHP `$array[$key]` means throw an `ErrorException` if it's not there and `@$array[$key]` means use `null` to mean not found (like an SQL `LEFT JOIN`).